# Does a strictly convex and continuous function always exist?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space, and let $C$ be a nonempty convex subset of $X$. A real-valued function $f: C \to \mathbb R$ is *strictly convex* if for all $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and distinct $x,y \in C$
$$f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) < \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y).$$

> Does a strictly convex, continuous, real-valued function exist on every nonempty convex $C$?

Comment: Hervé proved that that a compact convex set $C$ admits a strictly convex continuous real function iff $C$ is metrizable. You can find it in Alfsen's book as Theorem I.4.3.

Answer (score 4):

No, not necessarily. In particular, consider some infinite-dimensional normed linear space $X$, but equip $X$ with the weak topology. Suppose there was a weakly continuous, strictly convex function from $C = X$ to $\Bbb{R}$. By adding affine functions and translating the graph as necessary, we may assume without loss of generality that $f$ achieves a minimum of $0$ at $0 \in X$.

Since $f$ is weakly continuous, $f^{-1}(-\infty, 1) = f^{-1}[0, 1)$ is a weakly open set. Weakly open sets in $X$ must contain a finite-codimensional affine subspace, and since $X$ is infinite-dimensional, this subspace is non-trivial. Choose a line contained in this non-trivial affine subspace, and identify it with $\Bbb{R}$. The result is a strictly convex function
$$g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$$
such that $g(x) \in [0, 1)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

But, this is impossible! Pick two distinct points $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $x_1 < x_2$. Then, if $x > x_2$,
$$g(x_2) \le \frac{x_2 - x_1}{x - x_1}g(x) + \left(1 - \frac{x_2 - x_1}{x - x_1}\right)g(x_1).$$
Take the limit as $x \to \infty$, remembering that $g(x)$ is bounded, and we see that $g(x_2) \le g(x_1)$. But, on the other hand, if $x < x_1$, then similarly,
$$g(x_1) \le \frac{x_2 - x_1}{x_2 - x}g(x) + \left(1 - \frac{x_2 - x_1}{x_2 - x}\right)g(x_2),$$
hence as $x \to -\infty$, $g(x_1) \le g(x_2)$. That is, $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$, hence $g$ is constant, contradicting $g$ being strictly convex.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, but there are some parts of the argument that I don't understand. (1) Why is $f^{-1}(- \infty, 1) = f^{-1}[0,1)$. (2) Can you add a reference or explain "weakly open sets must contain a finite-codimensional affine subsapce"? (3) Same for "Choose a line...identify it with $\mathbb R$".

Comment: @aduh (1) I assumed without loss of generality that $0$ is the minimum of the strictly convex function, by adding on an appropriate affine function. You can argue this by choosing a support point on the epigraph of the function. This will generate a supporting hyperplane, and subtracting this from the function will produce a strictly convex function which attains a minimum. By adding a constant, this minimum could be $0$. (That said, we actually don't need the minimum to be attained at $0$, whoops, but it doesn't hurt).

Comment: (2) The weak topology is generated by the subbasis $\phi^{-1}(a, b)$, where $a < b$ are in $\Bbb{R}$ and $\phi$ is a continuous linear functional. Geometrically, this is the strip of space between the two parallel hyperplanes $\phi^{-1}\{a\}$ and $\phi^{-1}\{b\}$. A basic weakly open set is a finite intersection of such sets, and let's say they're generated by functionals $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n$ Then choosing a point $x$ in the basic open set, and direction vector $u$ in the intersection of the kernels of these functionals will yield a full line in the open set.

Comment: (3) The resulting line has a vector equation of the form $x + tu$ as $t$ ranges over $\Bbb{R}$. By setting $g(t) = f(x + tu)$, we obtain a strictly convex set, and since $x + tu$ lies in the weakly open set $f^{-1}[0, 1)$, then $g(t) \in [0, 1)$ for all $t$, hence the result follows.

Comment: By the way, I get that these are some significant clarifications. Are there any you want added to the body of the answer (or clarified further)? I left them off for the sake of brevity, but if you think it needs more detail, I can oblige.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think I follow. Am I correct in thinking that the argument works when $f$ is merely upper semi-continuous?

Comment: How does your argument relate to the result reported in KeeperOfSecrets' comment?

Comment: @aduh A strongly continuous convex function is automatically weakly **lower**-semicontinuous, due to the epigraph being a closed set in $x \times \Bbb{R}$ with respect to the product topology of the weak topology on $X$ and the usual topology on $\Bbb{R}$. In terms of KeeperOfSecrets' comments, I haven't heard of this theorem, but certainly $X$ is not compact or metrisable. Possibly of interest: if $X$ is a separable, reflexive space, then the unit ball is metrisable and compact in the weak topology, so a strictly convex weakly continuous function should exist.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify my question. It looks to me like the continuity of $f$ is used only to say that $f^{-1}(-\infty,1)$ is open, which is also true if $f$ is merely usc. So does your argument show that there's no strictly convex usc function as well?

Comment: @aduh That's right. Since lsc is automatic, usc is the unattainable goal.

Comment: @user837206 Another functional ninja!